# Hot to fix error "No space left on device" inside a docker image?

Tags: docker

I am creating a docker image, then I run the image as

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash testimage2
```

On the docker shell I find out that all space is taken up:

```
$ df .
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
none            51475068 49256704         0 100% /
```

How to change the creation of the docker image so there is still some space left inside the docker image?

Hint: The solution given to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203168/docker-says-no-space-left-on-device-but-system-has-plenty-of-space) does not work as docker does not seem to have a command `daemon`.

Comment: what output for `df -h` in host ?

Comment: In `home` I have plenty of space.

Comment: how about in `/var/lib/docker` in host ?

Comment: The `df .` command is run inside or outside the container?

Comment: I do not see any `/var/lib/docker` in `df`.

Comment: The `df` command above is run inside docker!

Comment: I just removed some old docker images on the host, now I have space inside the docker image. That is strange anyway